# Bootstrap progress bar, placing text on "Stacked" bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Maybe I am missing something simple, but I am trying to place some text on the Stacked bar for Twitter-Bootstrap's progress bar: [Stacked Bar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-stacked).

```
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 50%">
      <span class="sr-only">50%</span>
   </div>
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width: 20%">
      <span class="sr-only">20%</span>
   </div>
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 30%">
      <span class="sr-only">30%</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Hx6Sh/)

I am simply trying to get text to display on each segment of the stacked bar (50%, 20%, 30%), but I cannot figure out the correct implementation.

Comment: I placed a p tag after your span and the text appeared. Take a look... http://jsfiddle.net/Hx6Sh/1/ EDIT: I removed the sr-only class and it showed as text. :)

Comment: Must be the `sr-only` class hiding the text.

Comment: `sr-only` is for screen readers, to be blind-people friendly, it is invisible otherwise. remove that and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Twitter Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-screen-readers), the `sr-only` class is ment to hide an element to all devices except from screen readers. So in this case it hides the labels you want to show on all other devices except SRs.

Remove the class and it works.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx6Sh/2/).

Comment: you have it backwards: it hides text used by screen readers from other people who might be confused by it.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I might have written it unclear :-) EDIT: Updated. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: ah interesting! Thanks!